# ¿Es válido agarrar fragmentos de código HTML, CSS o JS y unifacarlos en un snippet?

Tags: discusión

Lo que pasa es que me he encontrado con preguntas que ponen el código HTML, CSS o JS como *código a secas.* Pienso mejora la pregunta juntar esos códigos en un solo snippet, para evitar los comentarios de *¿qué obtienes?*. Según [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit),

> - ...
> - para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla

Pienso que esto de editar la pregunta y juntar todo en un snippet clarifica la pregunta (de cierta manera) y sin cambiarla. Por que al final de cuentas es el mismo código, la única diferencia es que este es reproducible por otros usuarios.

Quería pregunta, para ver si estoy equivocado.